# Is it ok to write "as if it was"?

Tags: grammar

I just read this sentence and was wondering if it is okay to write it like this.

> You can use your device worldwide, **as if it was** directly connected to your
>   PC.

Are there better alternatives for writing this sentence? Maybe:

> You can use your device worldwide, **just like it is** directly connected to your
>   PC.

Comment: The original sentence is perfectly correct and idiomatic. Your suggested alternative conveys the same meaning, but I'd say it's less idiomatic.

Comment: Can i write `as if it were directly connected to your PC.`

Comment: Yes - indeed some would say that's more correct than "as if it was", because you're using the subjunctive mood.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use your device worldwide, just like **when** it is directly
>   connected to your PC.